# Apple Reporter returns "Invalid username and password" with valid credentials

Tags: app-store-connect, java-client, apple-reporter

I've been using [Apple Reporter](http://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/?lang=en#/itcbe21ac7db) for several weeks without issue, but yesterday (7/20/2017) all my calls fail unexpectedly.  My token is valid, I've refreshed and replaced it and setup a new account as an additional test. I can find no status or support page for this java client that Apple provides.

For anyone else using this client, are you experiencing the same issue (or have you encountered this before)?  Below is the XML returned by the java client, but I am 100% certain that my username and password are, in fact, valid. No code changes or other changes were made on my side of this integration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Error>
    <Code>108</Code>
    <Message>Invalid username and password. Change values and try again.</Message>
</Error>
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Apple coincidentally just released a new version of the Reporter:

> We’ve also updated Reporter to let you generate an access token with the new generateToken command. To use this new command, [download Reporter 2.2](https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/?lang=eng#/apda86f89da5).

^ one important note about the above, is a noticeable change in the Reporter.properties file. Mode is defaulting to Normal, UserId is gone, and AccessToken replaces the Password option.  Make sure you update all the details accordingly and then you'll be back on track.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Apple have just released version 2.2 of the Reporter, which fixes this issue. You may need to alter your Reporter.properties file to use an Access Token instead of Username/Password.

https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/?lang=eng#/apda86f89da5

---

I had the exact same issue as you, also starting on 20th.
I don't know what is causing it, but have found that I am able to download the report I need using this tool:

https://github.com/fedoco/itc-reporter

If you need to get it to work on a Windows or Linux PC (ie not a Mac) then you can just remove the word "keychain" from the import line (line 33) of reporter.py and run the tool with the -T option to pass it your Access Token.

Comment: Thanks, Adrian.  I'll take a look at this today.  If the data format is the same, then this may be my solution (and I'll check this off as solved). Great to know that I'm not the only one experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I racked my head on this for a couple weeks and got through this. I set up a batch script on my PC months ago and stopped working as you described. I downloaded 2.2 and was getting the same errors after going through the correct configuration.

What you need to do is open your Properties.config file on a Mac. Insert your access token and save it. Then use on your PC and it should work.

To repeat, configure the Properties.config file on a mac, and then you can use it on a PC.